# Neo4j graph database 2.2.1

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-mazerunner

i want to test the Neo4j Mazerunner service developed by Kenny bastani. and i need the **neo4j 2.2.1**. Please can anyone help me to find **the install of neo4j 2.2.1**, because i don't find it in the Neo4j website, their is only the latest versions.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Some older neo4j versions are available [on this page](http://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/). It does not have 2.2.1, but it does have 2.2.9, which might be suitable for your needs.

Comment: @kenny bastani please i want to test the **neo4j mazerunner**, and i don't find the install of **neo4j 2.2.1**. could i test with the **neo4j 2.2.9**? if not can you please share with me the neo4j 2.2.1. thank you